# iPad Mini 6 battery drain overnight without activity

Tags: ipad, battery

I used my otherwise normally functioning iPad some days back and let it charge to full via USB connected to a Macbook (while sharing the internet from the tablet to the Mac). After shutting down the Macbook and turning off the iPad screen in the evening, but still leaving the devices connected over USB, I woke up to find that the iPad had lost about 90% charge.

When checking the battery usage for the last 24 hours there had been 0 minutes of usage while the screen was on and also 0 minutes while it was off. It also said further down that ”usage per app is not available” for the hours when the battery discharged. I did not take a screen shot at the time so can`t show this with a picture.

Does anyone have a clue what could be the cause? Could it be that my battery didn’t really charge over the USB cable connected to the Macbook, even though the meter went up?

Comment: What's the temperature of the place the devices were in?

Comment: Just room temperature, about 22 deg Celsius.